# FLUTTER: When testing cubit, loading state isn't emitted, only loaded state is

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-test

When I run my app normally, I execute  `cubit.getWeather('London')` and the weatherLoading state emits, then weatherLoaded state emits CORRECTLY.

However when I run test for the cubit to test `cubit.getWeather('London')`, the weatherLoading  state isn't emitted - it jumps straight to weatherLoaded state.

Why is this happening?

State:

```
@freezed
abstract class WeatherState with _$WeatherState {
  factory WeatherState.weatherInitial() = WeatherInitial;
  factory WeatherState.weatherLoading() = WeatherLoading;
  factory WeatherState.weatherLoaded(Weather weather) = WeatherLoaded;
  factory WeatherState.weatherError(String message) = WeatherError;
}
```

Cubit:

```
class WeatherCubit extends Cubit<WeatherState> {
  final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;
  static Weather weather;

  WeatherCubit(this._weatherRepository) : super(WeatherState.weatherInitial());

  Future<void> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    emit(WeatherState.weatherLoading());
    try {
      final weather = await _weatherRepository.fetchWeather(cityName);
      emit(WeatherState.weatherLoaded(weather));
    } on NetworkException {
      emit(WeatherState.weatherError("Network error"));
    }
  }
}
```

My weather repository class has `'Future<Weather> fetchWeather(String cityname){...}'` method.

And finally, my test:

```
class MockWeatherRepository extends Mock implements WeatherRepository {}

void main() {
  MockWeatherRepository mockWeatherRepository;
  WeatherCubit cubit;

  final weather = Weather(cityName: 'London', temperatureCelsius: 7);

  setUp(() {
    mockWeatherRepository = MockWeatherRepository();
    when(mockWeatherRepository.fetchWeather(any))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => weather);

    cubit = WeatherCubit(mockWeatherRepository);
  });
  test(
    'emits [WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded] when successful',
    () async {
      cubit.getWeather('London');

      await expectLater(
        cubit,
        emitsInOrder([ //Fails
          WeatherState.weatherLoading(),
          WeatherState.weatherLoaded(weather),
        ]),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: I Have the exact same problem, and cannot find out why emitsinorder only tracks the last emit. When i debug, i can see that he emits the other states.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a day of pause, I found a solution.
Put the expectLater before the cubit "act".
As i read from resoCoder as example of a bloc:

> It is usually not be necessary to call expectLater before actually dispatching the event because it takes some time before a Stream emits its first value. I like to err on the safe side though.

I guess this is not true for cubits and you should always call expectLater before calling the method on the cubit.

```
test(
'emits [WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded] when successful',
  () {
    expectLater(
      cubit,
      emitsInOrder([ //Fails
        WeatherState.weatherLoading(),
        WeatherState.weatherLoaded(weather),
      ]),
    );
    cubit.getWeather('London');
  },
);
```

Alternative approach, from reading bloc_test:
You can use blocTest:

> blocTest creates a new cubit-specific test case with the given
> description. blocTest will handle asserting that the cubit emits the
> expected states (in order) after act is executed. blocTest also
> handles ensuring that no additional states are emitted by closing the
> cubit stream before evaluating the expectation.

In my case just moving the test to bloctest worked like i expected the test to work.

```
  blocTest('emits [WeatherLoading, WeatherLoaded] when successful',
  build: () => WeatherCubit(mockWeatherRepository),
  act: (WeatherCubit cubit) {
    when(mockWeatherRepository.fetchWeather(any)).thenAnswer((_) => weather);
    cubit.getWeather('London');
  },
  expect: [
    WeatherState.weatherLoading(),
    WeatherState.weatherLoaded(weather),
  ]);
```